# How to show for a linear ODE system, the solution can be given as the linear relation $p(t)=K(t)x(t)+s(t)$??

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, optimal-control

Suppose we have the following ode system:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot x(t) \\ \dot p(t) \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} && a_{12} \\ a_{21} && a_{22} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ p(t) \\ \end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix} r_1(t) \\ r_2(t) \\ \end{bmatrix};$$
is it always correct to suppose $p(t)=K(t)x(t)+s(t)$? How can we show this relation holds?

Comment: Definitely not if $a_{21}=0$.

Comment: Let's suppose the coefficients are so that we can get such solution. I mean how do we know that such linear relation may exist.

Comment: What is stopping you chosing $K(t) = 0$ and $s(t) = p(t)$?

Comment: This is an optimal control problem and finding p as a function of x is very beneficial; we can always find x and p as a function of t but this solution is not good from implementation point of view. But I don't know why this relation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p(t) = Kx(t)+s(t)$. If your coefficients are constant, then:
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = K\frac{dx}{dt} + s'(t) = a_{21}x+a_{22}p + r(t)$$
implies that:
$$Ka_{11} = a_{21}, Ka_{12} = a_{22}.$$
If your coefficient matrix is not constant, you can work the same.